# ViewState custom saving method - is it possible?

Tags: jsf, viewstate

AFAIK in JSF ViewState is stored into JVM memory when `javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD` is set to "server".

Is there any way to configure / setup a custom saving method that, for example, can use some (eventually, disk backed) storage engine (ie. memcache / redis) to store ViewState ?

Something like the equivalent of a custom `session.save_handler` in PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *is stored into JVM memory*

To be more precise, it's stored in the HTTP session which is in turn managed by the container.

So, if you want to customize session management, then just do it at the servletcontainer level. It's unclear which one you're using, but in case of for example Tomcat, refer the [Manager Component](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/manager.html) document under the chapters "Persistent Manager" for session storage on disk.

Comment: In that case, start at [Creating and Managing Sessions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2418/beaha.html). Checkout the "Session Managers" section.